# Неправильная кодировка прочитанного значения из sqlite базы

Tags: delphi, кодировка, delphi-7, sqlite, база-данных

Есть sqlite база данных - описатель, содержащая список таблиц, список доменов, список полей, список ограничений (первичных и внешних ключей), список индексов. Я подключаюсь из Delphi XE3 c помощью встроенного компонента к этой базе. Есть отдельный модуль, в котором описанны классы TTableSpec, TFieldSpec, TConstraintSpec, TConstraintDetSpeс. Эти классы соответствуют записям вышеупомяноутой sqlite базы. В классах типа ТTableSpec есть такие поля типа `FFields : TComponent`, которое делается владельцем объектов типа TFieldSpec, также выгруженных из базы. После создания объектов путем чтения базы-описателя я обнаружил, что значения некоторых свойств объектов (например, TFieldSpec) находятся не в той кодировке(строка `Edit2.Text:=TFieldSpec(TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldSpec).FieldName;` в нижеприведенной функции проверки на то, что является поле первичным ключом данной таблицы).

```
function TfmSettings.IsPrimaryKey(InputTableName : string; InputFieldName: string):Boolean;
var
  i : integer;
  flag: boolean;
begin
  flag:=False;
  for i:=0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.ComponentCount-1 do
    begin
      if ((TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).ConstraintType='PRIMARY') and (TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Fields.FindComponent(InputFieldName).Name=TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldName)) then
        flag:=True;
      Edit1.Text:=TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).Name;
      Edit2.Text:=TFieldSpec(TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldSpec).FieldName;
      Edit3.Text:=InputFieldName;
    end;
  Result:=flag;
end;
```

Привожу также код процедур, создающих объекты, связанных с неправильной кодировкой:

```
procedure CreationListOfFields(SQLConn: TSQLConnection; DBSchema : TDBSchemaSpec);
var
  NameField : TField;
  PositionField : TField;
  DescriptionField : TField;
  CanInputField : TField;
  CanEditField : TField;
  ShowInGridField : TField;
  ShowInDetailsField : TField;
  IsMeanField : TField;
  AutocalculatedField : TField;
  RequiredField : TField;
  Name1 : TField;
  Name2 : TField;
begin
    SQLConn.Execute('select f.id, f.position, f.name, f.description, f.can_input, '
    +' f.can_edit, f.show_in_grid, f.show_in_details, f.is_mean, f.autocalculated, f.required, t.name, d.name '
    +' from fields f left join tables t on f.table_id=t.id '
    +' left join domains d on f.domain_id=d.id order by t.name, d.name ', nil, results);
    if not results.IsEmpty then
      begin
        results.First;
        Name1:=results.FieldByName('name_1');
        Name2:=results.FieldByName('name_2');
        lastTable:=Name1.AsString;
        TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(lastTable));
        lastDomain:=Name2.AsString;
        DomainSpec:=TDomainSpec(DBSchema.Domains.FindComponent(lastDomain));
        NameField:=results.FieldByName('name');
        PositionField:=results.FieldByName('position');
        DescriptionField:=results.FieldByName('description');
        CanInputField:=results.FieldByName('can_input');
        CanEditField:=results.FieldByName('can_edit');
        ShowInGridField:=results.FieldByName('show_in_grid');
        ShowInDetailsField:=results.FieldByName('show_in_details');
        IsMeanField:=results.FieldByName('is_mean');
        AutocalculatedField:=results.FieldByName('autocalculated');
        RequiredField:=results.FieldByName('required');
        while not results.Eof do
          begin
            if (Name1.AsString<>lastTable) then
            begin
              lastTable:=Name1.AsString;
              TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(lastTable));
            end;
            if (Name2.AsString<>lastDomain) then
            begin
              lastDomain:=Name2.AsString;
              DomainSpec:=TDomainSpec(DBSchema.Domains.FindComponent(lastDomain));
            end;
            FieldSpec:=TFieldSpec.Create(TableSpec.Fields);
            FieldSpec.Setup( DomainSpec, PositionField.AsInteger,
            NameField.AsString, DescriptionField.AsString,
            FieldToBoolean(CanInputField),FieldToBoolean(CanEditField),
            FieldToBoolean(ShowInGridField), FieldToBoolean(ShowInDetailsField),
            FieldToBoolean(IsMeanField),FieldToBoolean(AutocalculatedField),
            FieldToBoolean(RequiredField));
            TComponent(FieldSpec).Name:=NameField.AsString;
            TableSpec.Fields.InsertComponent(FieldSpec);
            results.Next;
          end;
      end;
end;

procedure CreationListOfConstrAndConstrDet(SQLConn : TSQLConnection; DBSchema : TDBSchemaSpec);
var
IDField : TField;
NameField : TField;
ConstrTypeField : TField;
ReferenceField : TField;
UniqueKeyIdField : TField;
HasValueEditField : TField;
CascadingDeleteField: TField;
ExpressionField : TField;
NameField1 : TField;
Name1 : TField;
begin
    SQLConn.Execute('select c.id, c.name, constraint_type, reference, unique_key_id, has_value_edit, '
    + 'cascading_delete, expression, t.name from constraints c left join tables t on c.table_id=t.id order'
    +' by t.name ', nil, results);
    if not results.IsEmpty then
    begin
    results.First;
    IDField:=results.FieldByName('ID');
    NameField:=results.FieldByName('name');
    ConstrTypeField:=results.FieldByName('constraint_type');
    ReferenceField:=results.FieldByName('reference');
    UniqueKeyIdField:=results.FieldByName('unique_key_id');
    HasValueEditField:=results.FieldByName('has_value_edit');
    CascadingDeleteField:=results.FieldByName('cascading_delete');
    ExpressionField:=results.FieldByName('expression');
    Name1:=results.FieldByName('name_1');
    lastTable:=Name1.AsString;
    TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(lastTable));
    while not results.Eof do
    begin
    if (Name1.AsString<>lastTable) then
    begin
      lastTable:=Name1.AsString;
      TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(lastTable));
    end;
    ConstraintSpec:=TConstraintSpec.Create(TableSpec.Constraints);
    ConstraintSpec.Setup(IDField.AsInteger,NameField.AsString, ConstrTypeField.AsString,
    ReferenceField.AsString, ConvertToInt(UniqueKeyIdField.AsString), FieldToBoolean(HasValueEditField),
    FieldToBoolean(CascadingDeleteField), ExpressionField.AsString);
    TComponent(ConstraintSpec).Name:=results.FieldByName('name').AsString;
    TableSpec.Constraints.InsertComponent(ConstraintSpec);
    SQLConn.Execute('select cd.id, f.name from constraint_details cd left join'
    +' fields f on f.id=cd.field_id where cd.constraint_id = '+inttostr(ConstraintSpec.ID), nil, results1);
    if not results1.IsEmpty then
    begin
    results1.First;
    NameField1:=results1.FieldByName('name');
    while not results1.Eof do
    begin
     FieldSpec:=TFieldSpec(TableSpec.Fields.FindComponent(NameField1.AsString));
     ConstDetSpec:=TConstraintDetailSpec.Create(ConstraintSpec.DetailList);
     ConstDetSpec.Setup(NameField1.AsString, FieldSpec);
    ConstraintSpec.DetailList.InsertComponent(ConstDetSpec);
    results1.Next;
    end;
    end;
    results.Next;
    end;
    end;
end;
```

P.S. SQL-запросы выполняются в sqlite нормально. Выдает нужные строки в нужной кодировке (по крайней мере визуально результат содержит читабельные английские и русские символы).
Привожу также код классов:

```
unit DatabaseClasses;

interface

uses Classes;

type
TDataTypeId = (DataTypeId_String, DataTypeId_SmallInt, DataTypeId_Integer, DataTypeId_Word,
               DataTypeId_Boolean, DataTypeId_Float, DataTypeId_Currency,
               DataTypeId_BCD, DataTypeId_FmtBCD, DataTypeId_Date,
               DataTypeId_Time, DataTypeId_DateTime, DataTypeId_TimeStamp,
               DataTypeId_Bytes, DataTypeId_VarBytes, DataTypeId_Blob,
               DataTypeId_Memo, DataTypeId_Graphic, DataTypeId_fmtMemo,
               DataTypeId_FixedChar, DataTypeId_WideChar, DataTypeId_LargeInt,
               DataTypeId_Array, DataTypeId_FixedWideChar, DataTypeId_WideMemo);

TAlignSpec = (AlignSpec_Left, AlignSpec_Right, AlignSpec_Center);

TFieldSpec=class;
TConstraintDetailSpec = class;
TIndexDetailSpec = class;

TDBSchemaSpec=class(Tcomponent)
  private
    FDomains: TComponent;
    FTables : TComponent;
  public
    procedure Setup();
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Domains: TComponent read FDomains;
    property Tables : TComponent read FTables;
end;

TDomainSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FName: string;
    FDescription: String;
    FDataTypeId: TDataTypeId;
    FLength: Cardinal;
    FCharLength: Cardinal;
    FPrecision: Cardinal;
    FScale: Cardinal;
    FWidth: Word;
    FAlign: TAlignSpec;
    FShowNull: Boolean;
    FShowLeadNulls: Boolean;
    FThousandsSeparator: Boolean;
  public
    procedure Setup(FName: string; FDescription: String; FDataTypeId: TDataTypeId;
    FLength: Cardinal;FCharLength: Cardinal;FPrecision: Cardinal;FScale: Cardinal;
    FWidth: Word;FAlign: TAlignSpec;FShowNull: Boolean;FShowLeadNulls: Boolean;
    FThousandsSeparator: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property DataTypeId: TDataTypeId read FDataTypeId;
    property Length: Cardinal read FLength;
    property CharLength: Cardinal read FCharLength;
    property Precision: Cardinal read FPrecision;
    property Scale: Cardinal read FScale;
    property Width: Word read FWidth;
    property Align: TAlignSpec read FAlign;
    property ShowNull: Boolean read FShowNull;
    property ShowLeadNulls: Boolean read FShowLeadNulls;
    property ThousandsSeparator: Boolean read FThousandsSeparator;
  end;

TTableSpec= class(TComponent)
  private
    FFields : TComponent;
    FIndices: TComponent;
    FConstraints : TComponent;
    FName : string;
    FDescription: string;
    FCanAdd:  boolean;
    FCanEdit: boolean;
    FCanDelete: boolean;
  public
    procedure Setup(FName : string; FDescription:string;
    FCanAdd:  boolean; FCanEdit: boolean; FCanDelete: boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Description : string read FDescription;
    property Name : string read FName;
    property CanAdd:  boolean read FCanAdd;
    property CanEdit: boolean read FCanEdit;
    property CanDelete: boolean read FCanDelete;
    property Fields : TComponent read FFields;
    property Indices: TComponent read FIndices;
    property Constraints : TComponent read FConstraints;
  end;

TFieldSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FDomainSpec: TDomainSpec;
    FPosition: integer;
    FFieldName: string;
    FDescription: string;
    FCanInput: boolean;
    FCanEdit: boolean;
    FShowInGrid: boolean;
    FShowInDetails: boolean;
    FIsMean: boolean;
    FAutoCalculated: boolean;
    FRequired: boolean;
  public
    procedure Setup(FDomainSpec: TDomainSpec; FPosition: integer; FFieldName: string; FDescription: string; FCanInput: boolean; FCanEdit: boolean;
    FShowInGrid: boolean; FShowInDetails: boolean; FIsMean: boolean;FAutoCalculated: boolean;
    FRequired: boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property DomainSpec: TDomainSpec read FDomainSpec;
    property Position: integer read FPosition;
    property FieldName: string read FFieldName;
    property Description: string read FDescription;
    property CanInput: boolean read FCanInput;
    property CanEdit: boolean read FCanEdit;
    property ShowInGrid: boolean read FShowInGrid;
    property ShowInDetails: boolean read FShowInDetails;
    property IsMean: boolean read FIsMean;
    property AutoCalculated: boolean read FAutoCalculated;
    property Required: boolean read FRequired;
 end;

TConstraintSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FID:  integer;
    FDetails: TComponent;
    FName: string;
    FConstraintType: string;
    FReference: string;
    FUniqueKeyId: integer;
    FHasValueEdit: boolean;
    FCascadingDelete: boolean;
    FExpression: string;
  public
    procedure Setup(FID: integer; FName: string;
    FConstraintType: string; FReference: string; FUniqueKeyId: integer;
    FHasValueEdit: boolean; FCascadingDelete: boolean; FExpression: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property ID: integer read FID;
    property Name: string read FName;
    property ConstraintType: string read FConstraintType;
    property Reference: string read FReference;
    property UniqueKeyId: integer read FUniqueKeyId;
    property HasValueEdit: boolean read FHasValueEdit;
    property CascadingDelete: boolean read FCascadingDelete;
    property Expression: string read FExpression;
    property DetailList: TComponent read FDetails;
  end;

TConstraintDetailSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FFieldName: string;
    FFieldSpec: TFieldSpec;
  public
    procedure Setup(FFieldName: string; FFieldSpec: TFieldSpec);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property FieldName: string read FFieldName;
    property FieldSpec: TFieldSpec read FFieldSpec;
  end;

TIndexSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FDetails: TComponent;
    FID : integer;
    FName: string;
    FUniqueness: boolean;
  public
    procedure Setup(FID: integer; FName: string; FUniqueness: boolean );
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property ID : integer read FID;
    property DetailList:TComponent read FDetails;
    property Name: string read FName;
    property Uniqueness: boolean read FUniqueness;
  end;

TIndexDetailSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FPosition: integer;
    FFieldSpec: TFieldSpec;
    FExpression: string;
    FDescend: boolean;
  public
    procedure Setup(FPosition: integer; FFieldSpec: TFieldSpec;
    FExpression: string; FDescend: boolean  );
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property FieldSpec: TFieldSpec read FFieldSpec;
    property Position: integer read FPosition;
    property Expression: string read FExpression;
    property Descend: boolean read FDescend;
  end;
implementation

procedure TDBSchemaSpec.Setup;
begin
  FDomains := TComponent.Create(self);
  FTables := TComponent.Create(self);
end;

destructor TDBSchemaSpec.Destroy;
begin
  FDomains.Free;
  FTables.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TDomainSpec.Setup;
begin
  self.FName:=FName;
  self.FDescription:=FDescription;
  self.FDataTypeId:=FDataTypeId;
  self.FLength:=FLength;
  self.FCharLength:=FCharLength;
  self.FPrecision:=FPrecision;
  self.FScale:=FScale;
  self.FWidth:=FWidth;
  self.FAlign:=FAlign;
  self.FShowNull:=FShowNull;
  self.FShowLeadNulls:=FShowLeadNulls;
  self.FThousandsSeparator:=FThousandsSeparator;
end;

destructor TDomainSpec.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TTableSpec.Setup;
begin
  FFields := TComponent.Create(Self);
  FConstraints := TComponent.Create(Self);
  FIndices := TComponent.Create(Self);
  Self.FName:=FName;
  self.FDescription:=FDescription;
  self.FCanAdd:=FCanAdd;
  self.FCanEdit:=FCanEdit;
  self.FCanDelete:=FCanDelete;
end;

destructor TTableSpec.Destroy;
begin
   FFields.Free;
  FConstraints.Free;
  FIndices.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TFieldSpec.Setup;
begin
  self.FDomainSpec:=FDomainSpec;
  self.FPosition:=Fposition;
  self.FFieldName:=FFieldName;
  self.FDescription:=FDescription;
  self.FCanInput:=FCanInput;
  self.FCanEdit:=FCanEdit;
  self.FShowInGrid:=FShowInGrid;
  self.FShowInDetails:=FShowInDetails;
  self.FIsMean:=FIsMean;
  self.FAutoCalculated:=FAutoCalculated;
  self.FRequired:=FRequired;
end;

destructor TFieldSpec.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TConstraintSpec.Setup;
begin
  FDetails := TComponent.Create(self);
  self.FID:=FID;
  self.FName:=FName;
  self.FConstraintType:=FConstraintType;
  self.FReference:=FReference;
  self.FUniqueKeyId:=FUniqueKeyId;
  self.FHasValueEdit:=FhasValueEdit;
  self.FCascadingDelete:=FCascadingDelete;
  self.FExpression:=FExpression;
end;

destructor TConstraintSpec.Destroy;
begin
  FDetails.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TConstraintDetailSpec.Setup;
begin
   self.FFieldName:=FFieldName;
  self.FFieldSpec:=FFieldSpec;
end;

destructor TConstraintDetailSpec.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TIndexSpec.Setup;
begin
  FDetails := TComponent.Create(self);
  self.FID:=FID;
  self.FName:=FName;
  self.FUniqueness:=FUniqueness;
end;

destructor TIndexSpec.Destroy;
begin
  FDetails.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TIndexDetailSpec.setup;
begin
  self.FPosition:=FPosition;
  self.FFieldSpec:=FFieldSpec;
  self.FExpression:=FExpression;
  self.FDescend:=FDescend;
end;

destructor TIndexDetailSpec.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Простыня кода, и нигде нет описания базы или хотя бы таблицы проблемной.

Скорее всего у полей стоит отличная от остальной кодировка.

вот и перекодируйте эти поля, а как ни кто не скажет, пока вы не укажите в какой кодировке отдает результат и в какой вам нужно.

возможно будет вполне достаточно простых функций **AnsiToUTF8** и **UTF8ToAnsi**

Comment: @savro, а как узнать кодировку в sqlite? Или же кодировку `TFieldSpec(TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldSpec).FieldName;`, а также я хотел спросить: искал в интернете статьи по поводу кодировок в Delphi, какие есть функции перевода кодировок (вторая упомянутая функция не помогла, а на первую вылетает сообщение `Access violation at address 775EE891 in module 'ntdll.dll'. Read of address 00227004.`

Comment: @savro еще я пробовал перепечатывать определенное поле в sqlite таблице при щелчке на котором отображается значение не в той кодировке - не помогло.

Comment: > TFieldSpec(TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldSpec).FieldName

Это 5! Если за каждый символ да по рублю! Эх!